# How to parse GMT timestamp string in form of 1.337363185441E9 to Joda DateTime?

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using an API that returns GMT timestamps like 1.337363185441E9. How can I format this to Joda DateTime object? I have no idea how that's even a valid timestamp format. Maybe that's part of the problem...?

Comment: Do you know what the number represents (like number of milliseconds since xx/xx/xxxx)? Or do you know what date the specific number you give is supposed to represent? Would `2012-05-18T18:46:25.441+01:00` make sense?

Comment: Yeah that looks like the number of millis since the epoch (same as `System.currentTimeInMillis()`), except with an added fraction for nanoseconds.

Comment: @Torious Actually it looks like the number of seconds since the epoch, the fraction being the milliseconds.

Comment: Oh, you're right. My mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like seconds since the epoch. Off the top of my head, this would be:

```
long l = Double.valueOf("1.337363185441E9").longValue();
l = l * 1000;
DateTime d = DateTime(l);
```

Comment: Now to figure out why new Period(d, DateTime.now()).getDays() gives me six when the datetime is Fri May 18 17:46:25 GMT-0400 2012

Comment: Apparently I needed `Period p = new Period(dateTime, DateTime.now()).toStandardDays().toPeriod();`